# Not able to configure opencart in lap

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wampserver, opencart

[image]

I downloaded opencart 2.0.1.1 and have wampserver. I pasted upload file in wamp server and while trying to run it, I don't know what details sholud be filled in third step. That is, what is database name and paswords. I'm an absolute beginner, I have no experience in php.

Just trying to learn opencart.

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what you have tried/done? Otherwise, we could write a book on this. I am also assuming there is a typo in your title- lap vs. lamp?

Comment: thanks for the reply @closetnoc ill attach a screenshot.I did some research and added hostname and database name as told there. when i dpownloaded i got imgs of cmeras and all, so i am guessing there is a sample database with the download. i want to run the sample in my system and see what all i could do to it?

Comment: That will really help you to get an answer. I am not sure how much I can offer, I do not use Opencart for example. But maybe I can give some guidance in other areas.

Answer (score 1):

i just found why i was not getting it. click on wamp icon and go to phpmyadmin and click on database where u can see a database called mysql.
So add database name as : mysql and username :root , password: leave as blank , admin and password : anything u wish.

Maybe this is very simple .Posting it for starters who are stuck here.

Comment: Oh heck! I found some links for you that seemed to nail things down as well as it exists on the net. CONGRATULATIONS!! I am glad you found your answer!

Comment: You'll probably need to create a user and grant the user access to the database as well - unless this is also done for you? (There's _already_ a database called "mysql"? It is common to have to create a database for this purpose - particularly on the live server, since the PHP user should not have permissions to create databases.) Just to note, obviosuly you should never connect as the "root" user (particularly with no password!) in a live environment.